# Install Kali Linux on a Surface Pro 1

Tags: linux, boot, grub, microsoft-surface-pro

I really need your help; thanks in advance to anyone who can give me a hint!

I want to install Kali Linux on my Surface Pro 1. I found loads of tutorial with different sequence and tool used in different os, but none of them was completely useful for me.

I made a bootable drive with Kali 64bit, BOOTX64.efi and grubx64.efi.
Also, i created the grub.cfg file. I obtained a final structure like this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17863414/UII_Structure.png

Finally, after loads of try, I had the first screen opened with installation and live options.
Unfortunately, it doesn't matter what I choose (install, live, whatever) because I get a black screen with this sentence "Secure boot not enabled".

The secure boot is already disabled (as its needed) and I tryed to make it on without any changes.

I'm so upset, I found many videos with Kali working on a Surface but I'm probably doing something wrong....
I really hope someone will be able to help me.

Thank you very much, have a great day! 
Davide

Comment: RESOLVED - I found a solution. If anyone need help just send me a message. Byeee

Comment: What was the solution?